# How can I customize jQuery Mobile themes for buttons?

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile has a fine collection of themes for buttons.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html

However, I want a button with a red gradient in the background. I could just override the CSS for one button's theme directly, but is there way to do this without breaking jQuery Mobile's abstraction barriers?

In other words, can I add my own themes through the interface that jQuery Mobile offers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ThemeRoller at http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php

You can import the existing jQuery Mobile theme and then customize it. Note that if you have less than 5 themes, you need to edit the CSS yourself and specify the style for `.ui-body-e` because the error message uses it.